# PHP - Find multidimensional array search

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array where I need to find attribute name "Gallery" and retrieve value for this...in my test this should be "test_gallery". All with use of PHP. Just a note, order of data in array may change, order of last array will always stay...attribute_id, name, text.

Structure of this array is as per attached image.

PS: here is twig code that does same and works ok:

```
                    {% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
                      {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
                        {% if attribute.name == 'Gallery' %}                
                            {gallery}{{ attribute.text }}{/gallery}                             
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Here is php code I was trying to use:

```
        $arr = $data['attribute_groups']; //my array, print_r values are source of attached image

        foreach ($arr as $attribute_group){

                foreach($attribute_group as $attribute){
                    print('<pre>');
                    print_r($attribute);
                    print('</pre>');
                  if ($attribute['name'] == 'Gallery'){
                    print('<pre>');
                    print_r($attribute['text']);
                    print('</pre>');
                  }
            }
        }
```

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Create nested loops.

Comment: I was trying to have foreach twice than if but failed to have it correct

Comment: Share the code! Is the nesting staying as is it or can change too?

Comment: thank you for helping me. I have added code I was trying to use. nesting won't change

Comment: I should note, I have reason why I need to get that out of twig. This whole is from Opencart, where I need to get Gallery attribute text from twig into controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it using nested loops. Depending on the array archistructure, it can be done quite neatly.

I tested it with this code, written based on your attached image:

```
$attribute_groups = [
  4 => [
    'attribute_group_id' => 4,
    'name' => "Multimedia",
    'attribute' => [
        0 => [
          'attribute_id' => 26,
          'name' => "Gallery",
          'text' => "test_gallery",
        ],
      'attribute' => [
        1 => [
          'attribute_id' => 13,
          'name' => "Something",
          'text' => "test_something",
        ],
      ],
    ]
  ]
];
```

I did this to retrieve the group which contains the string that you seek:

```
$search = "gallery";
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
  foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $group) {
    if (key_exists('name', $group) 
        && strtolower($group['name']) == strtolower($search)
    ) {
      print_r($group['text']);
    }
  }
}
```

> test_gallery

Comment: No worries! @MartinStepanek